# How do I filter top_hits metric aggregation result [Elasticsearch]

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to group by address then get latest address by date then filter this results by there status.

```
ex
  {address: 'A', date: '10-10-1991', status: 'sold'}
  {address: 'A', date: '10-10-2016', status: 'active'}
  {address: 'A', date: '10-10-1981', status: 'sold'}

  {address: 'B', date: '10-10-2016', status: 'sold'}
  {address: 'B', date: '10-10-1771', status: 'sold'}
  {address: 'B', date: '10-10-1991', status: 'active'}

//Getting address with sold status should give me only this record {address: 'B', date: '10-10-2016', status: 'sold'} since most updated one in address A is an active status
```

I have this query in elastic search but its only upto grouping by address and getting latest date. I CANNOT filter this results by there status.

```
 {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "address"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "updated_date": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }]
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// This query gives me this records
{address: 'A', date: '10-10-2016', status: 'active'}
{address: 'B', date: '10-10-2016', status: 'sold'}
```

I want to get sold status from that results using elasticsearch

Comment: I don't understand the "filter this results by their status". If your `top_hits`only contains one result (i.e. `size: 1`)  what do you want to filter? Can you show what you get and what you would like to do that you cannot do?

Comment: @Val top_hits returns 1 result per group if size: 1.  so it doesnt only return one result if I have multiple groups.  Though in my example it would only return 1 result since it would only have 1 group (by address)

Comment: @Val updated question. thanks

Comment: Why don't you add a filter to your query to only consider addresses with `status: sold` then?

Comment: That gives me wrong results, it would instead give me {address: 'B', date: '10-10-2016', status: 'sold'} and {address: 'A', date: '10-10-1991', status: 'sold'}. since it filter it first before grouping and finding the most updated one.

Comment: Ok, I see now. What version of ES are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible with ES `2.x` using `pipeline aggregations`. First we need to aggregate on addresses. Then we use two aggregations, one which gets the latest_date and other which gets latest date for sold status. Then we check if both dates match with [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html). This is how it looks.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_address": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "address",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "date"
          }
        },
        "filter_sold": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "status": "sold"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "latest_sold_date": {
              "max": {
                "field": "date"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "should_we_consider": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "my_var1": "latest_date",
              "my_var2": "filter_sold>latest_sold_date"
            },
            "script": "my_var1 == my_var2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Good job @ChintanShah25.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Val, I appreciate that :)

Comment: Thanks @ChintanShah25 but is there a way to do this in elasticsearch v 1.4?

Comment: Only way I can imagine would be to implement `bucket_selector` logic in your server side or client side code. You will get `max_date` and `sold_max_date` for every address you have and then you would have to write code to compare it. on a side note It would be great if you could upgrade ES to latest version, mainly because it uses latest version of lucene which will give you lot of performance boost and obviously new features.

Comment: @ChintanShah25 what if I want the whole docs and not just the address (as key of the bucket)? Thx

Comment: This should be `"script": "params.my_var1 == params.my_var2"` instead of `"script": "my_var1 == my_var2"`