# Sorting and filtering elastic search top hits docs

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

lets say I have a simple product index for docs like this:

```
{
   "product_name": "some_product",
   "category": "some_cotegory",
   "price": "200"
   "sold_times": "5",
   "store": "store1"
}
```

and I want to get the most expensive products in their category and per store that have been sold less than 3 times and I want them to be ordered by store, category and price.

I can use two terms aggregations and top hits aggregation to get the most expensive products in their category per store, but how I sort and filter these top hits result? I really need to filter the results after the top hits agg is performed, so the filter query is not the solution. How can I do this? Thx

**EDIT:**

Long story short - I need elastic equivalent for SQL:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(price) AS price, categroy, store 
    FROM products
    GROUP BY category, store
) AS max_prices ON p.price = max_prices.price AND p.category = max_prices.category AND p.store = max_prices.store
WHERE p.sold_times < 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the search to only return products sold less than 3 times, then aggregate those by store and category, then finally apply a top hits aggregation to get the most expensive item in the category (for that store). Something like

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "sold_times": {
        "lt": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "store": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "store",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "category": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "most_expensive": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "price": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not what I want. It would give me false positive. My goal is to apply the filter after the aggregation is performed, not before. Let's say I have two products in category accessories, i.e. charger (price 200, sold_times 4) and headphones (price 100, sold_times 2). Your query would return product headphones. But that is not true. Headphones is not the most expensive product in category accessories. I need a query which would not return a product from category accessories at all, because the most expensive is the charger, but it was sold more than 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some search, I have found "possible" solution. I could use Bucket Selector aggregation, together with some script that would make accessible the top hits properties for filtering and similar approach for sorting using Bucket Sort aggregation (some info can be found here:  [How do I filter top_hits metric aggregation result [Elasticsearch]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848001/how-do-i-filter-top-hits-metric-aggregation-result-elasticsearch))

But I'm facing another issue with aggregations. Because a lot of categories I want to use a pagination (as "scroll" or "size and from" used in common search query) but it cannot be done easily with aggregations. There's a Composite Aggregation which could do something similar, but after all the query would be so complicated so it scares me a lot so I decided to give it up and make the grouping outside of elastic.

It is sad that there is no an easy way to do such a common analytic query in elastic.