# How do I filter after an aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to filter after a top hits aggregation to get if the first apparition of an error was in a given range but I can't find a way.

I have seen something about bucket selector but can't get it to work

```
POST log-*/_search/
{
  "size": 100, 
  "aggs": {
        "group":{
            "terms": {
                "field": "errorID.keyword",
                "size": 100
            },
            "aggs": {
                  "group_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                              "@timestamp": {
                                "order": "asc"
                              }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
            }
         }
       }
    }
}
```

With this top hits I get the first apparition of a concrete errorID as I have many documents with the same errorID, but what I want to find is if the first apparition is within a given range of dates.

I think that a valid solution would be to filter the results of the aggregation to check if it is in the range, but I don't know how could I do that.

Comment: How about simply adding a `range` query so that your top_hits would only show up if the date is in the desired range?

Comment: @Val but that would filter my hits, right? I want to know if the first apparition ever is in the selected range, I don't think that would do.

Comment: then you should add a `range` filter to your aggregation

Comment: @Val will that execute after top_hits?

Comment: You cannot filter top_hits after the fact, all you can do is run top_hits on a pre-filtered set of documents.

Comment: Isn't this a similar situation to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848001/how-do-i-filter-top-hits-metric-aggregation-result-elasticsearch ?  @Val

Comment: Except that the solution doesn't use `top_hits`.

Comment: I just realized... Is there another way to extract results in Elasticsearch if the first occurrence has happened in my range? Or the only way to do this will be to get all the first occurrences and then filter inside my program? @Val