# How do I filter top_hits metric aggregation result within ElasticSearch and get back multiple fields within ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I was trying to figure out how to filter out how to filter out the top_hits aggregation after it has been applied and found a solution here: [How do I filter top_hits metric aggregation result [Elasticsearch]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848001/how-do-i-filter-top-hits-metric-aggregation-result-elasticsearch)

Resulting in me getting a query like so:

```
'query': {
            'bool': {
                'filter': filterArr,
            },
        },
        'size': 0,
        'aggs': {
            'ids-aggregator': {
                'terms': {
                    'field': 'storeId.keyword',
                    'size': 10000,
                },
                'aggs': {
                    'latest_date': {
                        'max': {
                            'field': 'date',
                        },
                    },
                    'filter_sold': {
                        'filter': {
                            'term': {
                                'num_of_stores': 2,
                            },
                        },
                        'aggs': {
                            'latest_sold_date': {
                                'max': {
                                    'field': 'date',
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    'group_docs': {
                        'bucket_selector': {
                            'buckets_path': {
                                'my_var1': 'latest_date',
                                'my_var2': 'filter_sold>latest_sold_date',
                            },
                            'script': 'params.my_var1 == params.my_var2',
                        },
                    },
                    'sorted_buckets': {
                        'bucket_sort': {
                            'from': (page - 1) * pageSize,
                            'size': pageSize,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        _source: false,
    }
```

Although I do get the correct filtered storeIds and correct pagination, I cannot gain access to the other fields in my index. Looking at my query results I get this:

```
{
  took: 1331,
  timed_out: false,
  _shards: { total: 1, successful: 1, skipped: 0, failed: 0 },
  hits: {
    total: { value: 10000, relation: 'gte' },
    max_score: null,
    hits: []
  },
  aggregations: {
    ids-aggregator: {
      doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0,
      sum_other_doc_count: 0,
      buckets: [Array]
    }
  }
}
```

and inside the buckets within the ids-aggregator I get this:

```
[
  {
    key: 'efiqwofje1i312312',
    doc_count: 3,
    latest_date: { value: 7321321231 },
    filter_sold: { doc_count: 2, latest_sold_date: [Object] }
  },
  {
    key: 'fj3io21j4i3j21o31123',
    doc_count: 3,
    latest_date: { value: 3523153215312 },
    filter_sold: { doc_count: 2, latest_sold_date: [Object] }
  },
  {
    key: 'f3i2jf2oi1fjo2311',
    doc_count: 3,
    latest_date: { value: 4321431223431 },
    filter_sold: { doc_count: 2, latest_sold_date: [Object] }
  },
  {
    key: 'mfklqfmkdslang321231231',
    doc_count: 3,
    latest_date: { value: 43214321123414 },
    filter_sold: { doc_count: 2, latest_sold_date: [Object] }
  },
  {
    key: 'fdklasfjdslafjklqf1231231',
    doc_count: 3,
    latest_date: { value: 4321432412113421 },
    filter_sold: { doc_count: 2, latest_sold_date: [Object] }
  }
]
```

Is there a way to gain access to other fields in my index after the filters and pagination has been applied? Ideally I would like to use the top hits aggregation for the bucket_selector but was getting invalid queries

Comment: This is going to be possible as of 8.9.0: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/95828